# openpyxl read excel with filtered data throws error "ValueError: Value must be either numerical or a string containing a wildcard"

Tags: excel, openpyxl, filtered

When I use openpyxl(version 3.1.2) to read an Excel with filtered data using following code:
*wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)*
it throws an error "ValueError: Value must be either numerical or a string containing a wildcard".

If I deselect the filter function in excel sheet, it works fine.
but I don't want to deselect the filter function in Excel sheet, I expect the openpyxl.load_workbook(file) can work with filtered Excel sheet.

Comment: I realise that you cannot post comments, however adding a 'I have the same issue' as an answer to a similar question will only get the "answer" deleted as "not an answer". You should have mentioned this other question and noted that it doesn't help you because the solution calls for making a change you do not want.

Comment: Excel implements some **completely undocumented** functionality in filters which turn mathematical operators into text processors. We're still working on the best way to handle these.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, I will delete the comments below the answer, but I just found the comments was gone, maybe it was removed by system or someone.